# subprocess.check_output logical error

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I am running Xyce (SPICE simulator) simulation using `subprocess.check_output` because I want use its results for further analysis.

Here is the code I am using:

```
x=subprocess.check_output(['./Xyce','Circuit.cir'])
volt=[]
for i in range(1,4): 
    start=x.find('FINAL_COL{}_VOLT = ' .format(i)) + 18

    end=x.find('Measure Start Time')

    volt.append(x[start:end])
print colored ('volt=','cyan')
```

Here is the log I am getting for the Xyce simulation:

```
FINAL_COL1_VOLT = 0.0145203
Measure Start Time= 0   Measure End Time= 1
FINAL_COL2_VOLT = 0.0176678
Measure Start Time= 0   Measure End Time= 1
FINAL_COL3_VOLT = 0.0811186
Measure Start Time= 0   Measure End Time= 1
```

I am getting the result `volt=[' 0.0145203\n','','']` and I was expecting to get `volt=[' 0.0145203\n',' 0.0176678\n',' 0.0811186\n']`. I did some debugging and I found that the problem is my `end` because `'Measure Start Time'` is repeated after every result. So, when I tried to change my end to another string the code went through, but off course didn't give me the desired output because I am not stopping after I get the `VOLT` value.

So, an ideas on how I can solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `x.find('Measure Start Time')` returns the index of the **first** `Measure Start Time`

Comment: try `x.rfind(,,,)`, also might be a job for grep or re instead of trying to slice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not providing offsets for the `find` of `Measure Start Time`. Change the second `find` to:

```
end=x.find('Measure Start Time', start)
```

and the search for `end` will start from the `start` you identified, not the beginning of the string (which always finds the same `end`).

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the volts `re` might be a better approach:

```
lines = """FINAL_COL1_VOLT = 0.0145203
Measure Start Time= 0   Measure End Time= 1
FINAL_COL2_VOLT = 0.0176678
Measure Start Time= 0   Measure End Time= 1
FINAL_COL3_VOLT = 0.0811186
Measure Start Time= 0   Measure End Time= 1"""

import re

print(re.findall(r"(?<=_VOLT =\s)\d+\.\d+", lines))
['0.0145203', '0.0176678', '0.0811186']
```

Or split the lines pulling the lines you want:

```
print([line.split()[-1] for line in lines.splitlines() if line.startswith("FINAL")])
['0.0145203', '0.0176678', '0.0811186']
```